# Windows mobile shows incorrect image size

Tags: image, picturebox, windows-mobile-6.5, smart-device, motorola-emdk

I am trying to create an application for WinMobile using SmartDevice project in VS2008 for Motorola device. I am adding image to the form. It looks good in editor and emulator but when I run it on my device, image looks smaller in two times then original. What can I do with this?
All other controls looks exactly the same as they were in editor, only images im PictureBoxes are reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the AutoScale Settings and the FormFactor of your project: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/04/19/windows-mobile-6-5-changed-screen-geometry/

I assume you have set QVGA in the project and AutoScaleMode=DPI and run the project on a VGA device.

You can also change the picturebx to strech the image into the picture box size. So the image will be scaled up or down to fit the picture box.

Comment: Thank you, I changed FormFactor from Classic to Professional VGA and it works for me.